# Explain "kobject"

Tags: linux-kernel

I started reading *Linux Kernel Architecture* by Wolfgang Maurer.

Right in the beginning of the book he makes a note and tries to explain what `kobject`s are and their purposes.

So after reading and digging a little bit I have a couple of questions.

1. Sorry but what is a `kernel object`? Is it just a data structure like `task_struct`?
2. Please explain with a simple example from userland where and for what purpose `kobjects` are used ?

Comment: This isn't a request for learning materials. He's asking questions about the content of what he has been reading. This is a legitimate question.

Comment: Quote what the book says about kobjects. Otherwise you might get an answer which repeats exactly that.

Comment: @muru seems reasonable to assume anyone answering the question either knows the definition, or even has access to the source material...

Comment: @Thufir of what? The book? Why?

Comment: Possibly of the book, yes.  Anyone with an answer knows the definition for a kobject.  What added value would there be for quoting the book?

Comment: @Thufir the point is for the OP to highlight what part of the explanation they didn't understand. That way, we won't just repeat the same thing but will actually provide an answer that can help clear things up. It also shows that the OP has actually read something about the subject which is always a plus.

Comment: @FaheemMitha This is a legitimate question, but not for this site. A kobject is a Linux kernel concept of interest only for programmers. Programming is off-topic here.

Comment: Check [this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/an-argument-for-the-unix-specific-programming-questions-site-quality/3912#3912) meta post, it explains why was your question so brainlessly closed.